# How to shape rename sql.xml query xml elements

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following query

```
insert @p(target,type,val,[order])
        select "/session/verbs/put[@field='orno.f']",'string',141527,1
union   select "/session/verbs/put[@field='orno.t']","string",141527,2
union   select "/session/verbs/put[@field='orno.t']","string",141527,2
union   select "/session/verbs/put[@field='comp.f']","string",000,2
union   select "/session/verbs/put[@field='comp.t']","string",999,2.1
union   select "/session/verbs/setreport/parameter[@name='device']","string",105,3

set quoted_identifier on
SELECT  (SELECT target, type
         FROM @p

         FOR XML RAW, TYPE,ROOT('session')).query('/*');
```

and this returns

```
<session>
  <row target="/session/verbs/put[@field='comp.f']" type="string" />
  <row target="/session/verbs/put[@field='comp.t']" type="string" />
  <row target="/session/verbs/put[@field='orno.f']" type="string" />
  <row target="/session/verbs/put[@field='orno.t']" type="string" />
  <row target="/session/verbs/setreport/parameter[@name='device']" type="string" />
```

How can I modify the query to rename  `<row>`  to  `<parameter>`

Comment: Why do you want to? Wouldn't it be easier to adjust the part that consumes the XML that the elements are called `<row>`?

Comment: @Tomolak this is just the begining, I will need to add many more child elemements to this.. it perhaps makes sense to refer /session/parameters/parameter
/session/verbs/verb[@setreport]/parameter/...
than
/session/row/row..
etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you user SQL Server 2008 (R2) you may pass your parameter name after RAW derective:

```
FOR XML RAW('parameter'), TYPE,ROOT('session')).query('/*');
```

Comment: Thanks Aspirin, how is your blood thickness ?(:-